# State variable ignored by function with higher gas price

Tags: solidity

I found an issue with this contract, when I execute setValue and then requireValue functions in 1 block : if I use same gas price for both, I don't get any error.

```
contract test {
uint value = 0;

function setValue () public{ // execute with gas
    value = 10;
}

function requireValue () public{ // execute with gas
    require(value==10, "value is not 10");
}

function getValue () public view returns (uint){ // call
    return(value);
}

function resetValue () public{ // execute with gas
    value = 0;
}

}
```

But if I execute *setValue* with a normal gas price, then *requireValue* with more gas price than the first, I get the requireValue error "value is not 10". After the block mined, when I call *getValue*, I get 10.

It seems like the second function ignored the incrementation from the first because of the higher gas price, but it seems weird because the functioning of memory must be the same (I think the state variable doesn't wait for the block mined to change on-chain). Is there a solution for this issue,a way to communicate between functions ?

Comment: Based on your description, it seems that only one of the transactions (with higher or lower gas price) was actually executed. And the other is stuck in mempool or was rejected for some reason. Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can copy&paste and get the same result as you do. Code and set up that you're using to submit the transactions with different gas prices... With only the current code, I'm not able to reproduce the issue - if I send 2 separate transactions with different gas price, the resulting value is 2.

Comment: @PetrHejda I editted the contract, now it throws the error I found.

Comment: Improve the formatting of the text

Answer (score 0):

Transactions with a higher gas price are executed with a higher priority. So if you submit two transactions very quickly and one has a higher gas price then it is very likely that the higher price will be processed first even if you send the transaction second.